# How do I get my HTML file from a text file to the web?

Tags: html

I am new to programming and have now learned lots of HTML, CSS and Javascript I'd like to practice with. I have even put some test pages together in TextWrangler, but I cannot work out a way to publish them for free so that I can practice. I am working on a 2010 mac.

I have looked at various youtube videos, but so far have not been able to work out how to get from a text file on my computer to at the very least a preview of the page. I would really appreciate advice on a good free publishing method.

Many thanks,
Rachael

Comment: Right click and open the file, assuming it has the extension .html, with your web browser, probably Safari. That's the best preview you can get!

Comment: There's some free webhosting around. You can install a local webserver on your computer. Google is your friend. Advicing a library or tool is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Get a (free) host, upload your files to them via a method provided by them.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to publish your files:

- Create file with ending .html and doubleclick it. The standard browser will open. (E.g. php not available.)
- Install an apache server as localhost on your pc. Php, mysql db, etc. available.
- Create a free account at e.g. lima-city.de or anywhere else. Upload your files and test it.

Answer (score 0):

Save the document as "index.htm".
The file names of web pages must not have spaces and should end with the extension ".html" or ".htm".

Use your web browser (Mozilla, Chrome or Internet Explorer) to open the file you just saved. (Pull down the File menu to Open or Open Page..., navigate to the file and click Open.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on a Mac I recommend you get MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). There's a free version and this effectively makes a local server on your Mac. Other computers on the same network can access the websites on this server. You can even use PHP (if you really want to).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to view the file of your local PC then just save it with the .html extension and open it with a browser.
Otherwise get some free hosting and domain. You could probably try the .tk domains if they are still free and have hosting as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a **GitHub** account.
2. Create a repository, let's call it **"test"**
3. Create a **gh-pages** branch
4. Have at least an **index.html** file that you put into the repository on this branch
5. Check your webpage on **http://{your username}.github.io/test/**

Comment: Holy crap. For someone who have a hard time opening an html file in a browser, you raise the bar. It is not very simple to open a github account. Installing and running apache is much simpler :)

Comment: making an account by thinking of a username and a password is the easiest thing there is! If you made an account on StackOverflow or Facebook, you can make an account on Github. Everything else is just mouse clicking.

Comment: Maybe I confuse it with installing and reproing to my computer